# How to auto run a program on the client side after connecting to AD domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, autorun

How to run a program on the client desktop after connecting to Active Directory domain ?

Comment: I have an Active Directory domain running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Clients are a mixture of Windows7 and Windows 8. I want to run Vmware workstation on each machine, also I want this to happen on Logon and if the user close the program he will be logoff.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an Active Directory domain running on Windows Server 2008 R2.
>   Clients are a mixture of Windows7 and Windows 8. I want to run Vmware
>   workstation on each machine, also I want this to happen on Logon and
>   if the user close the program he will be logoff. –  Kacem Chammali

Use VMware view or Citrix XenDesktop.

You can put a desktop lock app to make the computer work like a terminal with citrix, surely the same with VMware. As when the user login, it auto connect them to their virtual desktop, and the logoff make the virtual desktop logoff & the workstation logoff too.

> Use with Receiver for Windows 4.2 when users do not need to interact
>   with the local desktop when using domain-joined machines, which are
>   SSON enabled and store configured. From:
>   https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/additional-client-software/receiver-desktop-lock-42.html

The software will cost you CAL, but you can save if you didn't bought yet all the VMware workstation license for each PC